# Google Cloud shell terminating after one hour

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-shell

I have a bash script which takes over an hour to run and for this reason the script terminates right in the middle. I did some digging around and found [this](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/limitations) limit. Is there anyway around this issue?

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the documentation you linked, Google Cloud shell isn't intended for long running jobs but for interactive use only.

One easy alternative is to create a Compute Engine VM instance in your project and execute your bash script from there. You can get a [f1-micro](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-types#sharedcore) instance running non stop [for free](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/always-free-usage-limits#compute_name) or choose a higher specs instance to speed up execution and stop the instance afterwards so you're only charged for the execution time.